Where is the PGAdmin4 location for saved queries
I've been using the save feature in the Query Tool for the queries I've been writing, and it's been working well for several weeks until today.  I had to restart my mac, and when I restarted PGAdmin4 (webclient via docker) I can no longer see any of the queries I'd saved.  Fortunately I still have my biggest one checked into git, but I had made a few updates since my last checkin, plus had saved a couple of smaller queries.
I created a test query and then searched my machine for it and can't find it anywhere.  The database I'm using is hosted on a server within our firewall.
Any ideas?  It's like it thinks I'm a new user and has created a different location for them.  If I log out and restart from docker I just see the new one I created.
Thanks in advance.
